# C hashtable pointer error

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

So I am making a hashtable in `main()` by calling a function training that takes as input 3 open FILES, and returns a hashtable pointer, and assigns to `hash_table_t hashtable` in main.  However, my problem exists when I try and pass `*hashtable` as a pointer in main to `read_query(*hashtable, query)` because I have first not initialized it as a pointer.

```
int main()
{
    int size
    FILE *D1 = fopen(fileLoc, "r");
    FILE *D2 = fopen(fileLoc, "r");
    FILE *D3 = fopen(fileLoc, "r");
    FILE *query = fopen(fileLoc, "w");

    ...
    hash_table_t hashtable = training(D1, D2, D3, size);

    ...
    read_query(*hashtable, query);

}

hash_table_t training (D1, D2, D3, size)
{
    hash_table_t *hashtable = create_new_hashtable(size);

    ....
    return *hashtable;
}
```

So my question is, how can you recast a structure that was not first initialized as a pointer,  because just calling `*hashtable` in main floods my console in errors, specifically...

`c:267:20: error: invalid type argument of unary _*_ (have _hash_table_t_)
         read_query(*hashtable, query);`

Comment: function `training` should be return pointer. E.g `hash_table_t * training (D1, D2, D3, size){ ... return hashtable;`, at main `hash_table_t *hashtable = training(D1, D2, D3, size);`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `hash_table_t` is a structure type (and not a pointer to structure) and that `create_new_hashtable` creates a hashtable on the heap with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Then you are dealing with pointers to hash table throughout, which means all your declarations are of type `hash_table_t *` and you pass around `hastable` variables without stars. You access the members with `hashtable->whatever`:

```
hash_table_t *training (FILE *D1, FILE *D2, FILE *D3, int size)
{
    hash_table_t *hashtable = create_new_hashtable(size);

    ...
    return hashtable;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
hash_table_t *hashtable = training(D1, D2, D3, size);

...
read_query(hashtable, query);
```

Please note that you should declare types for the parameters in `training`. Old C will make these arguments `int` by default, but modern C (from C99 on) prohibits default `int` declarations. Use C99.

Comment: Thank you, my program works now, I just have one question, why is it not necessary to call `*hashtable` in `read_query(hashtable, query)`?

Comment: What do you mean, call? Do you mean dereference? `hashtable` is a pointer, you pass around the pointer to the hash table. The functions that operate on the hash table dereference it by accessing the members with `->`. (Remember that `ht->x` ts the same as `(*ht).x`.)